# Adding Jquery UI to XSLTForms

Tags: jquery-ui, xforms, xsltforms

I was trying to add JQuery UI functionality and styling but I'm having problems with the CSS file. I use to attach a lot of libraries to XSLTForms files, but I really can't make it load. I already put the  and  tags inside the CSS file, as I use to do with other CSS files, but with no success.

Any idea what could be wrong? Functionality is OK, because Y can make it appear a dialog, but with no style. I copied the source code in a new file and change it to html (replacing the XForms tahgs with HTML ones) and everything worked ok. So I think there is something with XSLTForms.

```
<xf:trigger id="showDialog">
    <xf:label>Show dialog!</xf:label>
    <xf:load ev:event="DOMActivate" resource="javascript: 

        var dialog = document.createElement('div');
        dialog.innerHTML = 'Your modal dialog';

        $(dialog).dialog({
            autoOpen: true,
            modal: true,
            title: 'Attention',
            open: function(){
                $('.ui-widget-overlay').bind('click',function(){
                    $(dialog).dialog('close');
                })
            }
        });
    "/>
</xf:trigger>
```

I also unsuccessfully tryed to load this way:

```
<style type="text/css">
    @import url('res/jquery-ui.css');
</style>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This particular file had something than others don't: CSS comments. Just remove comments or make it as in the XML way (`<!-- A comment! -->`).

But for some reason, any image referenced is not loaded...

Answer (score 2):

XSLTForms requires CSS files to be XML Well-formed.

This option can be disabled including this processing instruction in your XForms:

```
<?css-conversion no?>
```

Take a look to this [XSLTForms Wikibook article](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/XRX/XSLTForms_and_eXist#Disabling_the_CSS_Conversion_Option)